# Using Multiple Ids in Ajax Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I have an autocomplete function which fills in areaname by looking up values in the database.  I would like to use this function on multiple ids (in two parts).  First the input text box which reads on key up such as

```
#user_areaname, #company_areaname, #job_areaname
```

and then fill in the ul list of the corresponding id such as

```
#user_areaname_list, #company_areaname_list, #job_areaname_list
```

So far I can use a class to pick up the data using a class and "this" but how do i get the corresponding list to populate.  The other long way is to write a separate function for each id which does not seem like smart programming.

**The html**

```
<input type="text" class="addpropertyinput autocomplete-list-completed" name="user_areaname" id="user_areaname" placeholder="Area Name" onkeyup="autocomplete_areaname()" maxlength="50"  />
<ul class="autocomplete-list" id="user_areaname_list"></ul>
```

**The jquery/ajax**

// Autocomplete Areaname -----------------------------------------------------------------

```
function autocomplete_areaname()
{
    var min_length = 3; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword2 = $('#job_areaname').val();
    if (keyword2.length >= min_length)
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'classes/autocomplete.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data:
            {
                keyword2: keyword2
            },
            success: function(msg)
            {
                $('#job_areaname_list').show();
                $('#job_areaname_list').html(msg);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $('#job_areaname_list').hide();
    }
}

// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item2(item)
{
    // change input value
    $('#job_areaname').val(item);
    // hide proposition list
    $('#job_areaname_list').hide();
}
```

**PHP**

```
if (!empty($_POST['keyword2'])){

    $keyword2 = '%'.$_POST['keyword2'].'%';
    $select = $con->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT areaname_name FROM tbl_areaname WHERE areaname_name LIKE (:keyword2) ORDER BY areaname_name ASC LIMIT 0, 5");
    $select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $select->bindParam(':keyword2', $keyword2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $select->execute();
    $data = $select->fetchAll();
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        // put in bold the written text
        $areaname_name = str_ireplace($_POST['keyword2'], '<b>'.$_POST['keyword2'].'</b>', $row['areaname_name']);
        // add new option
        echo '<li onclick="set_item2(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $row['areaname_name']).'\')">'.$areaname_name.'</li>';
    }
}
```

If I use classes such as

```
var keyword2 = $('.areaname').val();
$('.areanamelist').show();
```

Then all the divs with the class .areanamelist show the ul.

Also trying the code below but not working (no console errors also)

```
$("#job_areaname").keyup(function()
{
    var inputtextbox = "#job_areaname";
    var ullist = "#job_areaname_list";
    autocomplete_areaname();
    set_item2(item);
});
// Autocomplete Areaname -----------------------------------------------------------------
function autocomplete_areaname()
{
    var min_length = 3; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword2 = $(inputtextbox).val();
    if (keyword2.length >= min_length)
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'classes/autocomplete.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data:
            {
                keyword2: keyword2
            },
            success: function(msg)
            {
                $(ullist).show();
                $(ullist).html(msg);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $(ullist).hide();
    }
}
// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item2(item)
{
    // change input value
    $(inputtextbox).val(item);
    // hide proposition list
    $(ullist).hide();
}
```

Comment: all the data is coming from the same table in php, i.e query is the same so i have not given the php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use arrays (in both PHP and Jquery) to do it... I have tested it and it works....

Your HTML will look like this

```
<div class="autocomplete-list1">
<input type="text" class="addpropertyinput autocomplete-list-completed" name="user_value" id="user_value" placeholder="value" onkeyup="autocomplete_1()" value="<?php echo $data['user_value']; ?>" maxlength="50"  />
<ul class="autocomplete-list" id="user_value_list"></ul>
</div>
```

Your Jquery file will look like this

```
var selectedvalue = [];

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#user_value").keydown(function() { selectedvalue = ["#user_value", "#user_value_list", "value"]; }); 
}); 


// autocomplete ------------------------------------------

function autocomplete_1()
{
    var min_length = 3; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $(selectedvalue[0]).val();
    var arrayselector = selectedvalue[2];
    if (keyword.length >= min_length)
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'classes/autocomplete.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data:
            {
                keyword: keyword, arrayselector: arrayselector
            },
            success: function(msg)
            {
                $(selectedvalue[1]).show();
                $(selectedvalue[1]).html(msg);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $(selectedvalue[1]).hide();
    }
}

// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item(item)
{
    // change input value
    $(selectedvalue[0]).val(item);
    // hide proposition list
    $(selectedvalue[1]).hide();
}
```

Your PHP file will look like this

```
// autocomplete

    $arrayselector = $_POST['arrayselector'];

    if ($arrayselector == "value") { $searchvalue = array("value_name", "tbl_value"); }


    if (!empty($_POST['keyword'])){

        $keyword = '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%';
        $select = $con->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT $searchvalue[0] FROM $searchvalue[1] WHERE $searchvalue[0] LIKE (:keyword) ORDER BY $searchvalue[0] ASC LIMIT 0, 5");
        $select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $select->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $select->execute();
        $data = $select->fetchAll();
        foreach ($data as $row) {

            // select the column name based
            if ($arrayselector == "value") { $row = $row['value_name']; }

            // put in bold the written text
            $listvalue = str_ireplace($_POST['keyword'], '<b>'.$_POST['keyword'].'</b>', $row);
            // add new option
            echo '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $row).'\')">'.$listvalue.'</li>';
        }
    }
```

Then you can change the values in the arrays based on condition : ie. whichever element you want to autocomplete...

Comment: This works fine thanks... I guess the other way to do is passing parameters in function.. but this is working fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all input text boxes have same class i.e `addpropertyinput`, you can pass corresponding `input text box` object and its `ullist id` you want  to fill  to the function `autocomplete_areaname` dynamically.

So your code will be like

```
$(".addpropertyinput").keyup(function()
{
    var inputtextbox = $(this);
    var id = $(this).attr('id')  // returns input text box id
    var ullist_id = "#" + id + "_list" // forming corresponding ullist id from input text box id as you specified 
    autocomplete_areaname(inputtextbox, ullist_id);
});

function autocomplete_areaname(inputtextbox, ullist_id)
{
    var min_length = 3; 
    var keyword2 = inputtextbox.val();
    if (keyword2.length >= min_length)
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'classes/autocomplete.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data:
            {
                keyword2: keyword2
            },
            success: function(msg)
            {
                $(ullist_id).show();
                $(ullist_id).html(msg);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $(ullist_id).hide();
    }
}
```

For calling set_item2 function, add data attribute with `input text box id` to each `<li>` tag

like `<li data-input-text-id = "area_username"></li>`

click event for setting item value:

```
$(li).on("click", function(){
 input-text-box-id = $(this).attr("data-input-text-id");
 $("#"+input-text-box-id).val($(this).text());
```

})

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: autocomplete.js:72 Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (autocomplete.js:72)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.q.handle (jquery.js:3)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: set_item2 is not defined
    at HTMLLIElement.onclick (post-job:1)

Comment: both the solutions have problem setting the data, let me post the php also

Comment: I have updated logic for setting item value on click of li

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to take parameter, this way you'll be able to pass the id of different elements.

```
// the first parameter is the text input pass it like 'someid'
// the second parameter is where you want to display the results pass it like $('#someid')
// pass first parameter as a string 
function autocomplete_areaname(getValue, showResult) {
    var min_length = 3; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword2 = $('#' + getValue).val();
    if (keyword2.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'classes/autocomplete.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    keyword2: keyword2,
                    clas: getValue
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                    showResult.show();
                    showResult.html(msg);
                }
            });
    }
    else {
        showResult.hide();
    }
}
```

The set item function can done like the following.

```
// input is where we want to set the value and ulList is where we are going to select the values from 
// pass parameters like $('#someid')
function set_item(li, input) {
   input.val($(li).html());
   $(li).parent().hide();
}
```

And you can use this functions like this

```
// detect keyup and make AJAX calls
// pass first parameter as a string 
$('#user_areaname').on('keyup', function () {
    autocomplete_areaname('user_areaname', $('#user_areaname_list'));
});
$("#job_areaname").on('keyup', function () {
    autocomplete_areaname('job_areaname', $('#job_areaname_list'));
});
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['keyword2'])) {

    $keyword2 = '%' . $_POST['keyword2'] . '%';
    $class = $_POST['clas'];
    $select = $con->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT areaname_name FROM tbl_areaname WHERE areaname_name LIKE (:keyword2) ORDER BY areaname_name ASC LIMIT 0, 5");
    $select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $select->bindParam(':keyword2', $keyword2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $select->execute();
    $data = $select->fetchAll();
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        // put in bold the written text
        $areaname_name = str_ireplace($_POST['keyword2'], '<b>' . $_POST['keyword2'] . '</b>', $row['areaname_name']);
        // add new option
        echo '<li onclick="set_item(this,' . "'#$class'" . ')">' . $areaname_name . '</li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: autocomplete.js:111 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined at set_item2 (autocomplete.js:111) - unable to set value of item

Comment: both the solutions have problem setting the data, let me post the php also

Comment: on click li you want to hide the list and set the value in input?

Comment: the list is getting populated.. but on click the item is not getting set

Comment: again there is a problem with set item, i am slightly short on time so i will go the long way for now to write each function...  if possible please create a dummy dbase and two forms and test it...